# http://localhost:8080/sendRequest.htm 404 (Not Found)

Tags: spring

I have form.jsp.from that i am sending post request to a filter.
Now i am dispatching the request to controller in spring.Here i am Using custom annotations.Here i need to return response as String type not ModelAndView.Whats My Problem is The request coming to filter but not to controller.
Request is :/sendRequest.htm
Filter code is:RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/sendRequest.htm");
        rd.forward(request, response);
Controller is:

```
@Controller
public class ResponseController{
    @RequestMapping(value="/sendRequest.htm",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String sendResponse(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){

   return "msg";
}
```

And my spring-ser.xml is:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="myPackage" />  <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are mapping request to "/sendRequest.htm/sendRequest.htm", not to "/sendRequest.htm"
Just remove **@RequestMapping("/sendRequest.htm")** from class declaration, and leave it on method.

Comment: Exactly.  The request mapping for each method is appended to the request mapping for the class, so, in this case, you only need one or the other, but the best choice would be what white suggested.

Comment: Sir I just removed class level @RequestMapping,but Still request not goes to the controller.In the form.jsp my request is(/project/sendRequest.htm?action=enquiryform&fromReq=client)<br>i dont know how to dispatch request to the controller from filter.plz help me sir

Comment: What is servlet-mapping for DispatcherServlet in your web.xml?

Comment: Sir I want know something, is @RequestMapping works for two different dynamic webprojects which are in same server(tomcat6)? why bacause My "form.jsp" is in one project and "controller" in another project

Comment: Dispatcher will only look for resources that are in the context of the current app, so NOT

Comment: Sir its Working.I just checked my web.xml ,all the request are starts with *.do.then i added my request with .do then its working.but there is a slight problem like null values are stored.anyway thank u for responded me sir